# Tricky Custom post loop

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I'm building a site using "theretailer" as a base and I cant figure out where to place code to get the loop to work for a custom post type "News"? the loop the theme uses is

```
                //$wp_query->query('posts_per_page=1'.'&paged='.$paged);

                $wp_query->query('posts_per_page='.get_option('posts_per_page').'&paged='.$paged);

                while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
                ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>             

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

                <?php 
                if (function_exists("emm_paginate")) {
                    emm_paginate();
                }               
                ?>
```

I'd like to keep the same loop set up so I can use the built in paginate function?

Thanks

Comment: Your use of the `$wp_query` object here is, unusual to say the least. Was there a particular reason you couldn't create a standard WP_Query object and loop, or use the pre_get_posts filter like most code?

Answer (score 0):

To display 'news', you'll have to add it to your loop arguments:

```
$wp_query->query(
  'post_type' => 'news', 
  'posts_per_page='.get_option('posts_per_page').'&paged='.$paged
);
```